# Spotify API does not create private playlists

Tags: android, spotify

I am developing an Android app that creates Spotify playlists. When I create a playlist via the

```
https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}/playlists
```

endpoint, it is always public and the API seems to ignore the request body parameter ('public' of type Boolean) which should make the playlist private. However, it works well with the other parameters. I am using [kaaes's API wrapper](https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android) but I do not think it causes the problem.

My app's API scopes:

```
"playlist-read-private", "playlist-modify-public", "playlist-modify-private"
```

Java code for creating the playlist:

```
// API wrapper specific code
// Generic type Object is mandatory for the wrapper to work
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("name", mPlaylistTitle);
params.put("public", false);
params.put("collaborative", false);
params.put("description", mPlaylistDescription);

Playlist newPlaylist = service.createPlaylist(user, params);
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have access tokens?

Comment: Yes I received access tokens through the authentication code flow and the API does not reject my request. It just seems to ignore this one parameter...

Comment: I've just encountered the same issue, and I'm 99% sure this is a bug in their API. I've [submitted an issue](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/903).

Comment: Spotify has fixed the defect that @Thomi reported.